# How to identify logical contradiction in sorting conditions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, logic

I have a list of strings along with conditions that determine how they should be sorted.

The conditions can be simplified to the form, `X before Y` or `X after Y`.

However, one (or more) of the conditions contradict the rest.

Given a bunch of such conditions, I need to determine which conditions contradict the most other conditions so that I can eliminate the fewest conditions necessary to make them consistent with each other.

Once this is done, I will be able to reverse-engineer the original `sorted` array (which is not known to me).

The `conditions` below are consistent, but for illustration can be made contradictory in a way that causes an incorrect sorting by simply adding `'Sam' before 'Sue'`, as shown in the comments.

Such a tiny contradiction in such a tiny example can be identified by hand in a minute.  But my real life case involves a list of close to `100` strings, and a few hundred conditions.

I am seeking first an answer to the question, "Is it feasible to identify not just any contradiction, but the fewest contradictions possible that can be eliminated to leave consistent conditions?"

And second, hopefully some help in how to approach this.

The contradiction used as an example here is easy to identify.  But imagine if the conditions included among them, `'Sam' before 'Sue'`, `'Sue' before 'Bob'`, and `'Bob' before 'Sam'`.  Then it would not be nearly so obvious that there is a circular chain of conditions.

```js
'use strict';

const sorted = ['Sam', 'Sue', 'Bob', 'Dylan'];

const conditions = {
  Sam: {
    before: ['Sue', 'Bob', 'Dylan'],
    after: [],
  },
  Sue: {
    before: ['Bob', 'Dylan'], // adding 'Sam' causes incorrect sort
    // and contradiction, because it can't be both before 'Sam' and after 'Sam'
    after: ['Sam']
  },
  Bob: {
    before: ['Dylan'],
    after: ['Sam', 'Sue']
  },
  Dylan: {
    before: [],
    after: ['Sam', 'Sue', 'Bob'],
  }
};

const unsorted = ['Bob', 'Dylan', 'Sam', 'Sue'];

const resorted = [...unsorted].sort((a, b) => {
  if (conditions[a].before.includes(b)) return -1;
  if (conditions[b].after.includes(b)) return 1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(resorted); // [ 'Sam', 'Sue', 'Bob', 'Dylan' ]
```

When I first tried this with contradictory conditions, I had hoped that the `.sort()` method would enter an infinite loop as a way to tell me there was a contradiction.  But it actually sorts them anyway, just not correctly.

Otherwise I could have used trial and error to identify which conditions crashed the sorting function.

Comment: so in `conditions["Sam"]` its also contradiction because it cant be before or after `Dylan` ?

Comment: My mistake I will correct that, it's a typo.

Comment: But yes that is a contradiction.

Comment: First normalise your [ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order): convert all "X after Y" conditions into "Y before X". Then [find all circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection_(graph_theory)) and number them, and create a set of circle numbers for each condition in the circle. Now you'll want to find the minimum number of conditions to remove so that all circles are destroyed, which is the [NP-hard minimum set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem)

Comment: "*I had hoped that the `.sort()` method would enter an infinite loop as a way to tell me there was a contradiction*" - gladly not, there are so many broken comparison functions out there that would crash web pages… Notice the infinite loop is not detectable from the outside. You're looking for a [topological sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), which will detect contradiction and throw an error.

Comment: Thanks for the very insightful comments.  I may be in luck though; perhaps I'm having problems sorting my list with my conditions not because there is a hidden contradiction somewhere, but because the JavaScript built-in sort isn't thorough enough.  I will post a new question.