# Is JavaScript sort thorough?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I also have a sort function basically like this:

```js
const mySortingFunction = (a, b) => {
  if (a_before_b(a, b)) return 1;
  if (b_before_a(a, b)) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

Let's leave `a_before_b` and `b_before_a` as black boxes, since I think they would only distract from the issue.

```js
my_unsorted_list.sort(mySortingFunction);
```

This does a decent job at sorting my list.  Unfortunately, a handful of the about 100 elements are not correctly sorted.

I believe there are 3 possibilities.

- My black box functions are inconsistent with themselves or with each other
- The built-in JavaScript sort is not thorough
- Both of the above

In order to test the second theory, I stuck a `console.log({ a, b })` inside `mySortingFunction`.  I though it would have appeared **at least once** for each possible unique pairing of the array elements.

But it was far fewer than that.  About 4 times as many elements as there are in the list.

So I'm thinking that because my black box functions don't handle every possible case and sometimes `mySortingFunction` returns `0`, that is what is causing the imperfect sorting, where some elements are in a position that contradicts what is dictated by the black box functions.

This is about the same problem I posted about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63237270/13378247).

I hope someone can tell me which of the possibilities I listed can be the problem, or if there is something else I'm not considering.

To be clear, I'm not trying to judge the JavaScript built-in sort.  When I ask if it's "thorough" I mean, is it intended to be used the way I'm using it.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.  As you can see, even though the logic is consistent, the sort fails.  I presume in the below example (although I am not sure yet) there are not enough conditions.  But in my real life example, it's also possible the conditions aren't consistent.

I am trying to find out which, if either, is the case.

```js
const sorted = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const unsorted = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'];

const a_before_b = (a, b) => {
  if (a == 'a' && b == 'd') return true;
  if (a == 'b' && b == 'c') return true;
}

const b_before_a = (a, b) => {
  if (b == 'a' && a == 'c') return true;
  if (b == 'b' && a == 'c') return true;
}

const mySortingFunction = (a, b) => {
  if (a_before_b(a, b)) return -1;
  if (b_before_a(a, b)) return 1;
  return 0;
}

console.log(unsorted.sort(mySortingFunction)); // [ 'c', 'a', 'd', 'b' ]
```

Update!  I noticed that it sorted `'c'` before `'b'` even though my sort function clearly dictates this should not be the case:

```js
const b_before_a = (a, b) => {
  if (b == 'a' && a == 'c') return true; 
  if (b == 'b' && a == 'c') return true; // how did c get sorted before b?
}
```

Comment: what are you sorting? Numbers, text? If text, what character set are you using?

Comment: I'm sorting strings.  And `mySortingFunction` is supposed to produce a correct sorting via `a_before_b` and `b_before_a`.  But it doesn't, and I need to know if it's necessarily a problem with these 2 functions or not.  Because sometimes they "don't know" how to sort `a` and `b`, so the sorting function returns `0`.

Comment: Better still, can you give an example of the "badly-sorted" data?

Comment: I will try to write up a live example in a code snippet, hopefully using a very tiny dataset, if I can reproduce the problem with it.

Comment: Because the blackbox functions span maybe a few hundred lines of code, I did not post them here.

Comment: @user2864740 When I ask if it's "thorough", I mean, does it ensure that every possible pair in the list is sorted, even implicitly.  If that makes no sense hopefully the edit I will make soon will clarify.

Comment: As with all _sane_ sorts, no. It does not. A sort could not be O(n lg n) if it compared _all_ elements to _all_ elements.

Comment: Would such a sort enter an infinite loop with inconsistent conditions?  That would immediately tell me if my conditions are wrong.  Do you know the name of such a sort?  I need to try it.

Comment: @Nikkorian I added an example in the code snippet of badly sorted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort algorithm works. If an incorrect sorting function is supplied the result is “implementation-defined” and is a bug in the calling code.

Per [22.1.3.27 Array.prototype.sort](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-array.prototype.sort):

> **If comparefn [..] is not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array (see below), the sort order is implementation-defined.** The sort order is also implementation-defined if comparefn is undefined and SortCompare does not act as a consistent comparison function.

This is a basic requirement of all comparison sorts.

Sorts that run in O(n lg n) time such as merge sort or derivative don’t check all possible pair permutations. If a sort applied the comparison to all pair combinations it would take at least O(n^2) time — and would still not be guaranteed without a consistent comparison function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I hope you check out the bottom of my question where I posted an example illustrating my problem, and shed some more light for me.

Comment: b_before_a does not contain ‘d’, which is suspicious - without even considering anything else. Rewriting such in a single function, with a always the first conditional and b always the second, returning 1/-1 directly should show gaps: there more possible combinations than accounted for (a==c&&b==d is trivially missing, etc). Usually it makes sorting “easier” to linearize values.

Comment: But that just means it's incomplete.  Not inconsistent.  So why is the result inconsistent?  There is enough logic to ensure `c` does not come before `b`.

Comment: It is trivially inconsistent _because_ it is incomplete (and thus incorrectly returns “same” in cases). The sort function must _consistently_ return “before, after, same”. There is no “unknown” accepted.

Comment: Very interesting and that definitely answers my question.  Do you know what sort function I should use instead?

Comment: I need a sort which, on every iteration, pushes an element down until it's below every element it is known it must be below, and continues doing this until all elements are sorted.

Comment: I might open a new question focusing specifically on how to create a consistent sort function given some business rules. Starting at that premise will result in more focus and “real life” results. It may require showing additional surrounding context, as minimally as can be shown.

Comment: It’s quite possible to write some custom algorithm. That sounds like a _variation_ of a bubble sort might be suitable — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort (check out the animation under the Analysis)

Comment: I say _variation_, as bubble sort is still _not guaranteed to be of any use with an inconsistent/incomplete comparison function_. However, such may meet some business needs.. I’d consider linearizing the ordering instead.

Comment: I posted my new question here (in case you wanted to look): https://stackoverflow.com/q/63258995/13378247  I will have to research what "linearizing the ordering" means.  But I am surprised there is no sorting algorithm already that works with incomplete criteria.  I cannot be the first to need one.