# How to sort based on incomplete criteria?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

First I tried passing my own function to `Array.sort`, but it doesn't sort correctly.  Notice how `'c'` comes before `'a'` in the result, even though the case `if (b == 'a' && a == 'c')` is handled correctly.

These data are just for example.  My actual data is not to be alphabetically sorted.  It must use the logic illustrated in the `a_before_b` and `b_before_a` functions.

Since I only have conditions to determine the relative ordering of SOME (NOT all) pairs of elements, there may be multiple valid orderings of elements.  I just need to produce ANY valid ordering, where valid means does not contradict any of my conditions (which are defined in the `a_before_b` and `b_before_a` functions).

```js
const sorted = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; // I do NOT have access to this
const unsorted = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'];

const a_before_b = (a, b) => {
  if (a == 'a' && b == 'd') return true;
  if (a == 'b' && b == 'c') return true;
}

const b_before_a = (a, b) => {
  if (b == 'a' && a == 'c') return true;
  if (b == 'b' && a == 'c') return true;
}

const mySortingFunction = (a, b) => {
  if (a_before_b(a, b)) return -1;
  if (b_before_a(a, b)) return 1;
  return 0;
}

// doesn't produce correct sorting 
console.log(unsorted.sort(mySortingFunction)); // [ 'c', 'a', 'd', 'b' ]
```

Then I tried writing my own sort from scratch.  But it enters an infinite loop and I don't know why.

```js
const sorted = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const unsorted = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'];

const a_before_b = (a, b) => {
  if (a == 'a' && b == 'd') return true;
  if (a == 'b' && b == 'c') return true;
}

const b_before_a = (a, b) => {
  if (b == 'a' && a == 'c') return true;
  if (b == 'b' && a == 'c') return true;
}

const findAnUnsortedElement = array => {
  for (let [i, element] of Object.entries(array)) {
    i = +i;
    const a = element;
    const b = array[i + 1];
    if (b === undefined) return 'SORTING_COMPLETE';
    if (!a_before_b(a, b)) console.log(a, 'should not be before', b);
    if (b_before_a(a, b)) console.log(b, 'should be before', a);
    if (!a_before_b(a, b) || b_before_a(a, b)) return a;
  }
}

// from w3schools
function move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
  while (old_index < 0) {
    old_index += arr.length;
  }
  while (new_index < 0) {
    new_index += arr.length;
  }
  if (new_index >= arr.length) {
    var k = new_index - arr.length;
    while ((k--) + 1) {
      arr.push(undefined);
    }
  }
  arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
  return arr;
}

// enters infinite loop, never returns
const myCustomSort = array => {
  while (findAnUnsortedElement(array) != 'SORTING_COMPLETE') {
    const element = findAnUnsortedElement(array);
    const index = array.findIndex(el => el == element);
    console.log('moving', element);
    array = move(array, index, index + 1);
    console.log(array);
  }
  return array;
}

console.log(myCustomSort(unsorted));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm in the answer I gave earlier on, and which you (first) accepted, is really based on a heuristic.

For a sorted output to be guaranteed to not have any violations, you could treat this problem as a graph problem. Whenever two values can make a comparison that gives `true` (with either comparator function), then that pair represents an edge in the graph.

If the order is consistent, then there must be one value that is the least among the others, otherwise you would have a cycle.

So with that knowledge we can determine for each node in the graph how long the longest path is to such a least node. When you find the longest distance to such a least node, you can use the length of that path as an absolute order indication.

Here is an implementation:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.prev = new Set;
        this.order = 0; // No order yet
    }
    orderWith(other) {
        if (other === this) return;
        if (a_before_b(this.value, other.value) || b_before_a(other.value, this.value)) {
            other.prev.add(this);
        } else if (a_before_b(other.value, this.value) || b_before_a(this.value, other.value)) {
            this.prev.add(other);
        }
    }
    setOrder(path = new Set) {
        // Use recursion to find length of longest path to "least" node.
        if (this.order) return; // already done
        if (path.has(this)) throw "cycle detected";
        let order = 1;
        for (let prev of this.prev) {
            prev.setOrder(path.add(this));
            order = Math.max(order, prev.order + 1);
        }
        this.order = order; // If order is 1, it is a "least" node
    }
}

const a_before_b = (a, b) => {
  if (a == 'a' && b == 'd') return true;
  if (a == 'b' && b == 'c') return true;
}

const b_before_a = (a, b) => {
  if (b == 'a' && a == 'c') return true;
  if (b == 'b' && a == 'c') return true;
}

function mySort(arr) {
    // Create a graph: first the nodes
    let nodes = {}; // keyed by values in arr
    for (let value of arr) nodes[value] = nodes[value] || new Node(value);

    // Then the edges...
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            nodes[arr[i]].orderWith(nodes[arr[j]]);
        }
    }
    
    // Set absolute order, using the longest path from a node to a "least" node.
    for (let node of Object.values(nodes)) node.setOrder();
    
    // Sort array by order:
    return arr.sort((a, b) => nodes[a].order - nodes[b].order);
}

const sorted = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const unsorted = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'];
console.log(mySort(unsorted));
```

Comment: do you mind sharing some good resources about where someone can read more about this approach?

Comment: I'm going to try this function on my data as well.  I like that it seems to throw an error if there's a cycle; I really needed this feature also.  You can see the actual data I'm using in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63260287/13378247

Comment: This is indeed an implementation of a [depth-first topological sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Depth-first_search), although it does not build the list during the algorithm, but uses the "order" attribute for doing that in a separate `sort`.

Comment: This is fantastic!  I can also use it to determine which nodes have the same order, which I did not ask for but did actually need.

Comment: P.S. I have been looking for something that does precisely this on and off for an entire year.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

```
const unsorted = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'];
const sorted = unsorted.sort();
```

It should work I'm not sure what's your issue.

Comment: Maybe using letters for the example was a poor choice.  But my actual data is not letters, and I cannot use `Array.sort`.

Comment: I have to use the conditions I specified in `a_before_b` and `b_before_a`.

Comment: What is the actual data?

Comment: The actual data is a list of strings whose sorting cannot be inferred at all just by looking at the strings.  The strings themselves contain no info regarding their sorting.  That's why I have not shared them here.

Comment: Since I do not have access to a pre-sorted list, I don't know what the sort should look like beforehand.  So I can't add more if statements.  I don't have anymore.  I just need to get an ordering that does not contradict any of the if statements.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

```js
const sorted = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; // I do NOT have access to this
const unsorted = ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b'];

const a_before_b = (a, b) => {
  if (a == 'a' && b == 'd') return true;
  if (a == 'b' && b == 'c') return true;
  if (a == 'a' && b == 'c') return true;

}

const b_before_a = (a, b) => {
  if (b == 'a' && a == 'c') return true;
  if (b == 'b' && a == 'c') return true;
}

const mySortingFunction = (a, b) => {
  if (a_before_b(a, b)) return -1;
  if (b_before_a(a, b)) return 1;
  return 0;
}

// doesn't produce correct sorting 
console.log(unsorted.sort(mySortingFunction));
```

Comment: Thank you for the work you put into answering my question.  Unfortunately I was not clear enough.  I do not actually have access to a `sorted` list.  I don't know beforehand what the sorted list looks like.  And I don't have ALL the conditions.  Just some.  Based on the little info I have, I need to sort the list into ANY ORDERING (doesn't matter which) as long as the ordering produced does not contradict any of my conditions.  Your answer "cheats" because you inferred ALL the conditions based on the pre-sorted list.